# How to hide all tr from table except clicked one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide all `<tr>` of the table except on which I clicked.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>DEF</td>
        <td><i class="delete">delete </i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>DEF</td>
        <td><i class="delete">delete </i></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

On click of delete button hide all rows except current.

Jquery code:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table tbody tr').siblings().not($(this)).hide();
});
```

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `siblings` as follow:

See the comments inline in code:

```
// Bind click event on `tr` inside `table`
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    // Show current `tr` and hide others
    $(this).siblings().hide();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/LL0c2efg/

Answer (score 2):

You need to run your code under a click event handler, not when the page loads. Also note that `.not(this)` is redundant when using `siblings()` as the originating element would not be included anyway. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table tbody tr').click(function() {
        $(this).siblings().hide();
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L1g4ozrL/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table tbody tr').click(function(){
        $('table tbody tr').hide();
        $(this).show();
    })
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L1g4ozrL/1/)

Comment: Why you are hiding all the `tr` and then showing current