# Hide all Table Rows expect one selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table within my Spring MVC web application that uses JSP to serve up the data, the table is a dynamically loaded list of jobs to be worked on, what I am trying to do is when the table row is selected change the color of the Row to red and hide all other rows in the table.

The rows are getting highlighted but when I try to hide the rows I have no success, any ideas or help is much appreciated , please she what I have tried below with table structure.  Thank You

What happens when table data link is pressed is a form is opened with table data passed to form

Table:

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="no-more-tables" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">

                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Service Id</th>
                        <th>Vehicle</th>
                        <th>Due date</th>
                        <th>ServiceType</th>
                        <th>Last update</th>
                        <th>Frequency</th>
                        <th>Start</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody style="margin-bottom: 0px;">

                <tr id="table_row_id2" class="">
                    <td data-title="Service Id">2</td>
                    <td data-title="Vehicle">vehicle two</td>
                    <td data-title="Due date">2018-02-14</td>
                    <td data-title="ServiceType">Preventive Maintenance</td>
                    <td data-title="Last update">2018-02-14</td>
                    <td data-title="Frequency">Every 3 months, from finish date.</td>
                    <td data-title="Start"><a href='/inspections/?service_id=2' id="startLink">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
                                        </a>  </td>
                </tr>

                <tbody style="margin-bottom: 0px;">

                <tr id="table_row_id3" class="">
                    <td data-title="Service Id">3</td>
                    <td data-title="Vehicle">VAN1</td>
                    <td data-title="Due date">2018-02-20</td>
                    <td data-title="ServiceType">Preventive Maintenance</td>
                    <td data-title="Last update">2018-02-20</td>
                    <td data-title="Frequency">Every 3 months, from finish date.</td>
                    <td data-title="Start"><a href='/inspections/?service_id=3' id="startLink">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
                                        </a>  </td>
                </tr>


                </tbody>



            </table>
```

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(window).on('load',function(){
        var service_id = $('#service_id').val();
            if(service_id){
                $('#serviceRow').toggle();
                $('#table_row_id'+service_id).addClass('danger');
            $('#table_row_id'+service_id).siblings().hide();


            }

        });

});
```

Other way I approached:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $(window).on('load',function(){
         $( "table tbody tr" ).siblings( ".danger" ).hide();

      });
});
```

I have researched solutions on SO and on-line with no joy including this one:
[How to hide all tr from table except clicked one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30773857/how-to-hide-all-tr-from-table-except-clicked-one)

Please if you decide to down-vote my question please provide a reason as to why and we can try rectify the issue, thanks for your time, let me know if need anything else. Jason

Comment: can you post the final output of the table(in chrome dev tool), instead of the one with forEach. Also the link you shared didn't solve the problem? I mean did you use that like `$('table').on('click', 'tr', function () {`. When you click the `tr`, your code `$(window).on('load',function(){` will not fire.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai, I have added the table there for you.  I tried all the examples on the link but none seemed to work for me, maybe I did something wrong, could you explain why the S(window).on...will not fir? thank you

Comment: @NiK648 mentioned some of the issues with your code. Try to fix and check it out. Also your html structure is not the valid one. In your given table every row start with the `tbody` tag, which is wrong. that is a typo mistake or it is coming like that I am not sure.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai thanks for your input, I did not validate the html yet thanks for the spot, I will make this change my for loop started in the wrong place. thanks you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. 
 1. You are not attaching click event handler for the table row. You are writing the logic inside window `onload` event which won't trigger when you click on a row.
 2. You do not have any element with id `service_id`. I assume you are trying to get the content of the cell with `data-title="Service Id"`
 3. `val()` is used to get the value of input, select or textarea elements. To get content of cell, you need to use `text()` or `.html()`. See jquery documentation to understand the difference.

 4. You have wrapped each row in a `tbody` tag. As such, calling `sibling()` on the row elements will return empty collection.

Here is the working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/O33Xnwvg3yslLkG3DeHT?p=info

Comment: the service_id was a hidden field within the form and was not presented in the code snippet above my apologize, the tbody was a mistake I had the for loop positioned in the wrong starting place, and this was causing me the issue, this was why my code was not working, by providing your plunker and tips highlighted I was able to achieve my goal, so I am happy to except your answer....Thank you for your time and effort much appreciated